# How can we run a command with arguments on a pod using kubectl?

Tags: kubectl

For example something like this should work but gives some errors. It seems like arguments need to be single no argument calls?

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty pod 'cat myfile.txt'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it's is missing the `--` before the command. From [these docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec) for reference:

```
kubectl exec pod  --stdin --tty -- cat myfile.txt
```

But the usage for `kubectl` does show you can have have a command like that:

```
 kubectl exec (POD | TYPE/NAME) [-c CONTAINER] [flags] -- COMMAND [args...]
```